# Unable to call a function from a javascript loop to bind (via addEventListener) to a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rbq6920/)

Javascipt:

```
// Add your code here
LoadQuestion(1);

function LoadQuestion(questionId) {
  console.log('questionId ' + questionId)
  var data;
  if (questionId == 1){ //usually data comes from API
    data = {
      "Options": [
          {
              "OptionId": 2,
              "OptionText": "Application",
              "OptionType": "Link"
          },
          {
              "OptionId": 3,
              "OptionText": "License",
              "OptionType": "Link"
          }
      ],
      "QuestionText": "Hello, select one option",
      "QuestionType": "List"
  };

  } else if (questionId == 2 || questionId == 3){
    data = {
    "Options": [
          {
              "OptionId": 4,
              "OptionText": "Enter Date of birth.",
              "OptionType": "Date"
          },
          {
              "OptionId": 5,
              "OptionText": "Enter last four digits of SSN.",
              "OptionType": "Number"
          },
          {
              "OptionId": 6,
              "OptionText": "Enter your last name.",
              "OptionType": "Text"
          }
      ],
      "QuestionText": "License",
      "QuestionType": "Link"
    };
  }

  const defMsg = document.createElement("div");
  defMsg.append(document.createTextNode(data.QuestionText));
  defMsg.append(generateList(data.Options));
  appendChatMesage(defMsg)

}

function appendChatMesage(content) {
  console.log(content)
  $('#chat-body').append(content);
}

function generateList(jsonArray) {
            var ul = document.createElement('ul');

            // Loop through the JSON array
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
                var item = jsonArray[i];
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                if (item.OptionType == 'Link') {
                   //alert(JSON.stringify(item));

                    var link = document.createElement('a');

                    link.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        LoadQuestion(item.OptionId);
                    });
                    link.setAttribute('href', '#');
                    link.innerText = item.OptionText;
                    li.appendChild(link);

                    ul.appendChild(li);
                } else if (item.OptionType == 'Date') {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(item));
                    // Create the table dynamically
                    var dynamicTable = document.createElement("table");
                    dynamicTable.setAttribute("border", "1");
                    var initialRow = dynamicTable.insertRow(0);
                    var cell1 = initialRow.insertCell(0);
                    var cell2 = initialRow.insertCell(1);
                    cell1.innerHTML = item.OptionText;
                    cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text">';

                     li.appendChild(dynamicTable);
                    ul.appendChild(li);
                }
            }

            return ul;
        }`
```

The LoadQuestion is the entry point, it creates and passes data with div tag to another function (appendChatMesage).
The first attempt will load hyperlinks, user will click one of the link and it should pass the respective question id to LoadQuestion(so that we can pass to the API and it returns details for question 2)

issue: line # 74, I am binding a function to a dynamically created hyperlink, but the whatever is the last in the array gets binded to both items. Basically, LoadQuestion is getting the same arguments regardless of what we have in an array item.

I tried creating hyperlinks with hardcoed function calls like link.click = 'LoadQuestion(' + item.OptionId + '), but didn't worked and gave error that LoadQuestion not found.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion you can fix this by replacing `var` with `let` or `const`

Comment: you mean everywhere? because there is an additional issue which I was able to fix by removing const with var.

Comment: I think a single `var item` -> `let item` would fix this here. But I'd probably refactor the `for(var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++)` loop body to a separate function that returns the element for a given item.

Comment: @Phill your comment was helpful, using `const item` was the fix. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code a bit – the main point is that the function that returns the element for a given Option is its own function, so bindings are definitely in correct scope.

Also, no more jQuery...

```js
function getQuestion(questionId) {
  if (questionId === 1) {
    //usually data comes from API
    return {
      Options: [
        {
          OptionId: 2,
          OptionText: "Application",
          OptionType: "Link",
        },
        {
          OptionId: 3,
          OptionText: "License",
          OptionType: "Link",
        },
      ],
      QuestionText: "Hello, select one option",
      QuestionType: "List",
    };
  }
  if (questionId === 2) {
    return {
      Options: [],
      QuestionText: "Application?",
      QuestionType: "Link",
    };
  }
  if (questionId === 3) {
    return {
      Options: [
        {
          OptionId: 4,
          OptionText: "Enter Date of birth.",
          OptionType: "Date",
        },
        {
          OptionId: 5,
          OptionText: "Enter last four digits of SSN.",
          OptionType: "Number",
        },
        {
          OptionId: 6,
          OptionText: "Enter your last name.",
          OptionType: "Text",
        },
      ],
      QuestionText: "License",
      QuestionType: "Link",
    };
  }
  throw new Error("Invalid questionId");
}

function LoadQuestion(questionId) {
  console.log("questionId " + questionId);
  const data = getQuestion(questionId);
  const message = document.createElement("div");
  message.append(document.createTextNode(data.QuestionText));
  message.append(generateList(data.Options));
  document.getElementById("chat-body").appendChild(message);
}

function getOptionForLi(item) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  if (item.OptionType === "Link") {
    const link = document.createElement("a");

    link.addEventListener("click", function () {
      LoadQuestion(item.OptionId);
    });
    link.setAttribute("href", "#");
    link.innerText = item.OptionText;
    li.appendChild(link);
    return li;
  }
  if (item.OptionType === "Date") {
    const table = document.createElement("table");
    table.setAttribute("border", "1");
    const initialRow = table.insertRow(0);
    const cell1 = initialRow.insertCell(0);
    const cell2 = initialRow.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = item.OptionText;
    cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text">';
    li.appendChild(table);
    return li;
  }
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(JSON.stringify(item)));
  return li;
}

function generateList(jsonArray) {
  var ul = document.createElement("ul");
  for (const item of jsonArray) {
    ul.appendChild(getOptionForLi(item));
  }
  return ul;
}

LoadQuestion(1);
```

```html
<div id="chat-body"></div>
```